# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_instruments_list'

Tags: python

I use Windows 10 and Python 2.7.

When I use the `get_instruments_list()` function of the `visa` module, an error occurs.

```
insts = [inst for inst in visa.get_instruments_list() if 'GPIB' in inst]
```

error:

> ```
> insts = [inst for inst in visa.get_instruments_list() if 'GPIB' in inst]
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_instruments_list'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`get_instruments_list()` is from PyVISA 1.5
You need to change this to something like:

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()
```

So your code could be changed to:

```
insts = [inst for inst in visa.ResourceManager().list_resources() if 'GPIB' in inst]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're misusing the API. Check the documentation of PyVisa which supports python 2.7. Later check for 'get_instruments_list' function in the supported PyVisa for Python2.7